# Activar ion-checkbox según un array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic

¿Cómo puedo activar un ion-checkbox consultando a un array?
Vamos al código para entenderlo mejor.

Tengo el siguiente ion-checkbox

```
<ion-content *ngIf="contenidoCarga"> 
  <ion-item *ngFor="let cat of categorias">
    <ion-label>({{cat.id_categoria}}) {{cat.texto}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox slot="end" [(ngModel)]="cate"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let sub of subcategorias">
    <ion-label>({{sub.id_subcategoria}}) {{sub.text_subcategoria}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox slot="end" [(ngModel)]="subc"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let ele of elementos">
    <ion-label>({{ele.id_elemento}}) {{ele.txt_elemento}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox slot="end" [(ngModel)]="elem"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-button color="primary" (click)="Guardar()" slot="end" class="ion-margin-end">Guardar</ion-button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

La data después de consumir las Apis son las siguientes (Son varios objetos pero coloque uno para cada ejemplo):

categorias:

```
    "data": [
        {
            "id_categoria": 1,
            "id_padre": "root",
            "id_texto": 1,
            "texto": "CAMAS"
        },
...
    ]
```

subcategorias

```
"data": [
    {
        "id_padre": 1,
        "id_posicion": 1,
        "id_subcategoria": 11,
        "id_texto": 33,
        "text_padre": "CAMAS",
        "text_subcategoria": "BOX SPRING"
    },
    ...
]
```

elementos

```
"data": [
    {
        "id_elemento": 111,
        "id_padre": 11,
        "id_posicion": 1,
        "id_texto": 11,
        "txt_elemento": "1 PLAZA",
        "txt_padre": "BOX SPRING"
    },
  ...
]
```

La cosa va a asi, Esto me genera un modal con varios ion-checkbox. (En este modal de activaran o desactivaran los ion-checkbox para posteriormente guardar esos IDs, concatenarlos "1;11;111" e insertarlos en una tabla.

[image: Modal]

Lo que necesito es que se activen los ion-ckeckbox según los ids que me llegan de otra API.

```
    "data": [
        {
            "ids": "1;11;111",
            "sku": "780642749279-3"
        },
        ...
]
```

Para este ejemplo **al momento de abrir el modal** deberían estar activos el ion-checkbox "Camas", "Box Spring" y "1 Plaza".

Comment: ¿Qué son `cate`, `subc` y `elem`? No deberías bindear varios *checkbox* a una misma variable.

Comment: @VRoxa Si hago eso y selecciono un ion-checkox, se seleccionarán los que tengan el mismo ngmodel también...

Comment: y quieres que todos los checkbox de una misma categoria se seleccionen al unísono? para que sirve entonces?

Comment: @Klaimmore En ningún momento mencione eso, necesito lo que menciono en el post (Que se activen los ion-ckeckbox según los ids que me llegan de otra API y que si activo otros o desactivo otros me retorne estos ids en alguna variable) para poder insertarlos del mismo formato que me llegan.

Comment: no lo mencionas, pero el codigo lo refleja. Si dejas 2 `ngModel` referenciando una misma variable, ambas cambian al mismo tiempo. En lugar de eso, podrías referenciar a alguna propiedad de los objetos de las variables de iteracion `cat`, `sub` y `ele`, por ejemplo: `[(ngModel)]="cat.selected"`